# Вывод значений переменных в строке

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, foreach

Есть такой код

```
    foreach( $posts as $post2 ){
        setup_postdata($post2);
        $postId = $post2->ID;
        $goodImg = get_field('good_img',$postId);
        $url = $goodImg['url'];
        $alt = $goodImg['alt'];
        $postsHtml .= '<div class="good_thumb">'.
                            '<div class="img_box">'.
                                '<img src="$url" alt="$alt" />'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>';
}
```

Выводит он вот так

```
<div class="good_thumb"><div class="img_box"><img src="$url" alt="$alt"></div></div>
```

Не могу получить значения src и alt картинки. Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: $alt = $goodImg['alr']; очепятка?

Comment: Исправил, но все равно не выводит значения.

Comment: src="' . $url . '" alt="' . $alt . '"

Comment: + переносы строк с конкатенацией при формировании строки в переменной не нужны, бровзер сам всё как надо расставит.

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало!